# ENOENT error - while trying to download bitmap to computer

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to download a bitmap file to my computer but in the JPEG form. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Users/johnathan/Downloads");
    if (!myDir.exists()) {
        myDir.mkdirs();
    }
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpeg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ())
        file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Didn't work");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I keep on getting the error No such file or directory (ENOENT):

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Users/johnathan/Downloads/Image-4209.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:575)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
W/System.err:     at com.example.testforcamera.MainActivity.SaveImage(MainActivity.java:173)
W/System.err:     at com.example.testforcamera.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:115)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8659)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5857)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5903)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:567)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:273)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:567)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8523)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:561)
W/System.err:   ... 19 more
```

I have been looking all over the internet for a solution and nothing has worked. Most of the answers are pretty outdated though. Is there anyone here that possible has a solution? I have been working on this one part for hours now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the directory you are trying to save to (`Users/jonathan/Download`s) does not exist at the location returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` which returns the root of the android filesystem, not of that the computer's.

I do not know if/how you can access your computer storage from your android device, you might try using a USB on the go cable so that the android device acts as host (if it supports that feature) and the computer as external storage (although  windows has lots of trouble accessing android phones at all without special drivers so it's improbable it would allow external devices to access one of its partitions). Afterwards you need to check if/where the computer's partition ("C") is located on the phone's file system using a file manager app or by running a 'find' command in a terminal/console app on your android device.